# How to change ERT alignment in LyX to "left" instead of "block"?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx

LyX displays text in ERT layouts block aligned, and there is no "align" parameter for the inset layouts (such parameter exists for styles, and may take values such as Left, Block...).

I don't find it useful in any way to have ERT text displayed block-aligned in LyX, it's even inconvenient while editing and less readable, so I'm wondering is there any way I could change it to left-align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from LyX mailing list. It's by redefining the **Plain Layout** as follows:

```
Style "Plain Layout"
    Align Left
End
```

Comment: How do I apply this in Lyx?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my preambles and custom layouts:

```
InsetLayout ERT
    Align Left   # For readibility onscreen, regardless of justification in document
End
```